# Horizontal overflow for image akin to text?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Gif for visualization:
[here](https://pasteboard.co/GNGHbwE.gif)

How it works now: when my text gets longer, it overflows out of its bounds. This is the desired behavior. Why? Because no matter the length of the text, it always grows to the right horizontally.

What I want is to have the the horizontal length of the background image change dynamically based on the length of the text.

The hierarchy in the gif:

I have a parent button with a button script with three children.
-Background image
-Text
-Folder icon

The button script references the image for highlighting and clicking, the text displays on top of the image and the icon is displayed to the left of the folder name.

I tried a combination of HorizontalLayoutGroup and ContentSizeFitter whilst parenting the background to the text (or vice versa). In the end was able to get close to the desired behavior, as my text length increased, the image behind it did as well, but it wasn't scaling accurately (each single character would expand the image far too much and it stretched the width in both directions horizontally, where as I am looking for it to stretch in one direction).

The ideal behavior being that I can increase the text length in one direction (only to the right) and the button image behind it scales according to the length of the text.

Essentially is there an implementable behavior in the UnityGUI feature set to have a button image overflow in one direction akin to the way text does?

Please see image for visual aid. It shows an example with the background completely enveloping text, and one where it is not and the desired behavior be required to remedy the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I've done it :

- Folder Button : Horizontal Layout Group with Left padding set to icon width (100 units) + Content size fitter with `preferred size` in the horizontal fit

  - Background : Stretched RectTransform + Layout Element set to `Ignore Layout`
  - Icon : Width and Height set to 100 units + Layout Element set to `Ignore Layout`
  - Text : No component except Canvas Renderer and Text

[image: Elements]

[image]

Comment: Almost exact, fantastic! Please see: https://imgur.com/a/QDh6t You'll notice that it is working, but it pushes to the left. This can be remedied by dragging the parent folderButton's x-axis over. In addition, there is a parent that contains all these buttons with a Grid Layout Group. When that is enabled, the background snaps to the folder. It will still highlight the background when I go over the text, but again it is now only behind the folder icon.

Comment: Well, I think I had this problem in the past. Now, I follow the next rule : "Never put a layout group directly under a layout group". I always add an intermediate empty gameobject between. Here, put the FolderButtons in empty gameobjects and make those gameobjects children of your grid layout.

Comment: Figured out the horizontal alignment. Added an Layout Element to the Button and played around with the Preferred Width setting

Comment: Automatic layout in Unity is always a big mess. I dream that someday, we will have as flexibility as HTML + CSS3. Anyway.... Good luck!